# The Question in the About Page is about Unicorns eating Daisies?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Why not use an actual question from code review in the about page?

It seams that it would give people a better idea about how to ask questions, and what exactly this Q&A is for.

[image: Unicorns eating Daisies? -- About Page]

Comment: What exactly would you suggest should be there instead? Do you have any specific actual question in mind?

Comment: A question that is both well formatted, on topic, and the kind of question that would be good for this site.

When it comes to specific examples, I personally do not. I am decently new to code review and that is why I was looking at the about page.

Comment: Haha, I liked the unicorn question except for the fact I couldn't read all of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria for that question (and its answers) default to disallowing block elements, since they tend to take up too much room. I've turned this off here, since most questions and answers *must* contain code - this allows a few different questions to be used:

- [Looping over a list, checking a boolean and return value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/looping-over-a-list-checking-a-boolean-and-return-value)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14011/how-to-optimize-this-loop-algorithm
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/is-continue-considered-bad-style
- [Implementing a Singleton pattern in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79/implementing-a-singleton-pattern-in-c)

Note that these will be cut off, and even then the best (longest) answers will tend to be ignored - that's just the cost of having to fit them into a fairly concise page.

Answer (score 3):

At this time no question on code review qualifies for an about question. See here for details:

[What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page)

Until such time, we are stuck with unicorns.

Comment: I wonder if those requirements mean there will *never* be a fitting question. The requirements of CR are that code has to be included in each question, but the about-page question can't have any “fancy formatting”.